# Continuity of a ruler function.

Tags: real-analysis

A question from *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck:

Define the "ruler function" $f(x)$ as follows:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} {1/2^n}, & \text{if $x={b/2^n}$ for some odd integer $b$;} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

(a) Prove that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at the points $b/2^n$, ($b$ odd).

(b) Prove $f(x)$ is continuous at all other points.

I prove (a) by constructing a sequence {$x_n$} of irrational numbers whose limit is $b/2^n$. Then the limit of {$f(x_n)$} is $0$, since $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$. But $f(b/2^n)\ne 0$, discontinuity occurs. I don't know how to prove (b).

Comment: For part (b), if you want to land in a certain $\epsilon$ range of $f(x_0) = 0$, then just kick out all $\frac{b}{2^n}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n} > \epsilon$. There are only finitely many of these in any nbhd of $x_0$

Comment: @mathworker21 How to show "There are only finitely many of these in any nbhd of $x_0$" and there are infinitely many $b/2^n$ around $x_0$?

Comment: Use number theory. For example, if $\epsilon = .3$ and $x_0 = 0$, then in a neighborhood of radius $1$ around $x_0$, there's only $\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}$

Comment: @mathworker21 Then what? How to prove continuity?

Answer (score 1):

This problem calls for the standard $\epsilon,\delta$ style of proof. Here's a quick sketch of how you might begin:

Let $x\in\mathbb R$ be irrational, and fix $\epsilon>0$.

There exists an $n\in\mathbb N$  s.t.  $2^{-n}<\epsilon$. Thus it will be sufficient to choose a neighborhood around $x$ that excludes all values divisible by $2^{-m}$ for some $m<n$. All such values are of the form $2^{-n+1}b$ for some integer $b$. Can you find a $\delta$ that excludes all of these?

Let $d$ be half the minimum distance between $2^{n-1}x$ and an integer, that is:

$d = \frac 12\min\left(2^{n-1}x-\lfloor2^{n-1}x\rfloor, \lceil2^{n-1}x\rceil - 2^{n-1}x\right)$

We can be assured such a quantity exists, and since $x$ is irrational, $d>0$.

Notice that the interval $(2^{n-1}x-d,2^{n-1}x+d)$ contains no integers.
Multiplying everything by $2^{-n+1}$, we also see that the interval $(x-2^{-n+1}d, x+2^{-n+1}d)$ contains no numbers of the form $2^{-n+1}b$ for integer $b$. We can therefore choose $\delta=2^{-n+1}d$, or,

$\delta = 2^{-n}\min\left(2^{n-1}x-\lfloor2^{n-1}x\rfloor, \lceil2^{n-1}x\rceil - 2^{n-1}x\right)$

And the inteval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ contains no point $y$ for which $|f(y)-f(x)|\ge\epsilon$. The function is therefore continuous at any irrational point.

Comment: I am the asker. Sorry for my ingorance, I don't understand. Could you please explain more?

Comment: How would $2^{-n+1}b$ be divisible by $2^{-m}$? The quotient is $2^{m-n+1}b$, not necessarily an integer.

Comment: As an example, suppose $n=3$, this means that multiples of $2^{-3}=\frac 18$ are sufficiently small that there is no need to exclude them. However, we must ensure that our neighborhood does not include any multiples of $\frac 14, \frac 12, 1, ...$. All of these numbers will be divisible by $\frac 14$, so it is sufficient to ensure out neighborhood does not include any multiples of $\frac 14$.

Answer (score 0):

Writeup of mathworker21's answer. As the function is periodic with period 1, without loss consider the function on $[0,1]$. The set
$$ U_{n}= \{ x \in [0,1] : |f(x)|≥ 2^{-n}\} $$
Consists of the points $\frac12,\frac1{4},\frac 34,\frac18, \frac38,\dots,\frac1{2^n},\dots, \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$. In particular $U_n$ is a finite set. So if $x$ is not of the form $\frac{b}{2^n}$ with $b$ odd, then we have the strictly positive number $r$, defined by 
$$r= d(x,U_n) = \min_{y\in U_n} |x-y|> 0$$
From the definition of $U_n$, at points $x' \in B(x,r)$, $|f(x')|<2^{-n}$ (since $U_n \cap B(x,r) = \emptyset$). Also observe $0=f(x)$. Thus, the set of points $f(B(x,r))$ is contained in $$\{y\in f([0,1]):|y - f(x)| < 2^{-n}  \} = B(f(x),2^{-n}),$$
which, by choosing $n$ so that $2^{-n}<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0 $ was arbitrary, verifies [one definition of continuity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276258/open-balls-and-continuity)